# How to reset global String variable value

Tags: java

I need your help in resetting the value of a global String variable in my bean. In the bean, I have a variable:

```
private String total=""; //Generate Getters & Setters
```

The Setter & Getter code is:

```
public void setTotal(String total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public String getTotal() {
    return total;
}
```

I am having a void method which is called `getTotals()`, this method will be fired in a popup window. The value of the `total` variable will be retrieved from a query:

```
total = rs.getString("Earning_Amount");
```

After closing the popup dialog, I am calling a method which is called `closeDialog()` where I am assigning blank value of the `total` variable.

```
total="";
```

However, when I am printing the value of the total inside the `closeDialog()`, the total value will be blank. But, when I am printing the value in the getter method, it is showing me that it has a value and the reset is not done. So how to reset the global variable on the executing of the `closeDialog()` method as it is keeping the old value?

Comment: Could you post the code for the getter method?

Comment: need code for `closeDialog()` is that in bean too? if so then do a `this.total = "";` and yeah please provide code for getter() too

Comment: `"I am having a void method which is called getTotals(), in this, I am assigning a value to the total variable..."` -- then you will wan to rename this method since it is named as if it were a getter method, and such methods don't change state but instead they return state of the object. Perhaps call it `extractTotal`.

Comment: @RedRoboHood please refer to the updated post

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary Yes closeDialog() is in the same bean.

Comment: please try my answer.. you shouldn't put any business logic in a `getter()` method. So I have written a method, fetchTotal where the logic has been moved, then in `closeDialog()`, I do a `this.total="";` Hope it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class TotalBean{

    private String total = "";

    public void setTotal(String total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public String getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public String fetchTotal() {
        this.total = rs.getString("Earning_Amount");
        return total;
    }

    public void closeDialog() {
        this.total = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this and I will come back to you